# Withdraw all data from a SQL table to my Python code

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, cs50

This might seem obvious but I can't find how I can use the SELECT statement to withdraw all the data from a table to a list in my python code..

This is what I need: my table is called history and it has 7 columns, so I need to get every value for later show it on my html code

This is my code so far:

```
portfolio = db.execute("SELECT * FROM history WHERE id=:user_id;", 
user_id=session["user_id"])

symbol = portfolio[[0]'symbol']
name = portfolio[[0]'name']
share = portfolio[[0]'shares']
price = portfolio[[0]'price']
total = portfolio[[0]'total']
.
.
.
return render_template("portfolio.html", search = search, total = total, 
share = share, share_tot = share_total, trade = trade)
```

**Error:**

> symbol = portfolio['symbol']
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: sorry, I'm using SQLite

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a comma between the integer and string. Python is interpreting both of those together to be one and i believe you need to separate them. For example, you could put a comma between [0] and 'symbol to separate them, and do that for the rest of them.

Comment: Nope, same error:  symbol = portfolio[[0],'symbol']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: You could try changing it to: portfolio [0], ['symbol']